# Need to copy items from one listbox to another listbox using a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session, session-variables

Page 1: (sending listbox items into a list and saving the list as a session variable)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
{
    list.Add(item.ToString());
}
Session["temp"] = list;
```

Page 2: (copying the session variable into a list and assigning the list to a listbox in this page)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list = (List<string>)Session["JobRole"];
foreach (ListItem item in list)
{
    ListBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

On doing so, this is the error i m getting : Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

can anyone pls help me with this ??

Thanks

Comment: using two different session keys, is that a mistake while posting here?

Comment: Your session variables are different in the 2 pages, they should both be "temp" or "JobRole".

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mean

```
    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

... list is a list of `string`s after all.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have defined list as List.  If you simply want to add the string value into the listbox you can do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list = (List<string>)Session["JobRole"];
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Also you should check that Session["JobRole"] is not null.